# Google maps api works with manualy inserting json but not with inserting the same json from a python script

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps

Pretty new to this so thanks in advance. I am trying to pass a location_json with locations in an html file to show and route a map between them using google maps api. when i manually enter the location_json  it works fine ,for example like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map with Locations and Route</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #map-container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key"></script>
    <script>
        var location_json = [{"Location":"Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Artemonas, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Church of Panagia tis Kimisis, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Church of Panagia Mirtidiotissa, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece"}];
        
        var locations = location_json;

        function initMap() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            // Get coordinates of all the locations
            var locationCoordinates = [];
            var completedRequests = 0;

            function geocodeLocation(index) {
                if (index < locations.length) {
                    geocoder.geocode({ address: locations[index].Location }, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            locationCoordinates[index] = results[0].geometry.location;
                            completedRequests++;
                        } else {
                            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }

                        if (completedRequests === locations.length) {
                            createMapAndRoute(locationCoordinates);
                        } else {
                            geocodeLocation(index + 1);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            geocodeLocation(0);
        }

        function createMapAndRoute(locationCoordinates) {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 13,
                center: locationCoordinates[0]
            });

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ map: map });

            var origin = locationCoordinates[0];
            var destination = locationCoordinates[locationCoordinates.length - 1];

            var waypoints = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < locationCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
                waypoints.push({ location: locationCoordinates[i] });
            }

            var request = {
                origin: origin,
                destination: destination,
                waypoints: waypoints,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
                } else {
                    console.log("Directions request failed due to " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
    <div id="map-container">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but if i insert
`var location_json = {{ location_json|tojson|safe }};`
with the exact same location_json (copy pasted from print command in python terminal)
instead of
`var location_json = [{"Location":"Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Artemonas, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Church of Panagia tis Kimisis, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Church of Panagia Mirtidiotissa, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece"}];`
it gives a blank page with a console error
`Geocode was not successful for the following reason: INVALID_REQUEST`

i have tried changing the capitals and inserting commas between address city and country in the pandas file from which i create the json. The objective is to show a map with the locations a  route planned between them in the order they appear on the json

Comment: There is no python code in the question, why the python tag?

Comment: there is a python script that produces a pandas table , i then turn it to json with location_json = locations_df.to_json(orient='records') and then pass it to the html through render template. i thought it would be relevant just forgot to mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments - you do `location_json = locations_df.to_json(orient='records')` and pass `location_json` (i.e. JSON string) to template. Then inside the template you serialize `location_json` for second time using `tojson` filter. You should pass a list of dicts to the template.

See the difference:

```
data = [{"Location":"Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece"},
        {"Location":"Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece"}]

import json
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

templ = """var data = {{ data|tojson|safe }}"""
template = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(templ)

print(template.render(data=data))  # that is what you should do - pass `data` as list of dicts
print(template.render(data=json.dumps(data))) # that is what you do - passing JSON string
```

Rendered output

```
var data = [{"Location": "Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece"}, {"Location": "Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece"}]
var data = "[{\"Location\": \"Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece\"}, {\"Location\": \"Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece\"}]"
```

You can also check the source HTML of the generated "blank" page.

So, if your dataframe `df` looks like

```
                      Location
0    Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece
1  Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece
```

you can do

```
data = list(df.to_dict('index').values())
print(template.render(data=data))
```

will produce

```
var data = [{"Location": "Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece"}, {"Location": "Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I followed your suggestions. By adding a console.log(locations) i get that the locations variable is :[{"Location":"Platys Gialos Beach, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Kamares, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Apollonia, Sifnos, Greece"},{"Location":"Faros Beach, Sifnos, Greece"}] which is just as you said it would. But the map still doesn't show. What buffles me is that if i copy paste FROM THE CONSOLE the 'locations' output , paste it in the html as location_json, it works just fine , so i suppose the problem isnt in transfering the json from the python script

Comment: Could you check the actual code of the rendered html page? Clearly the generated page is not the same as when you copy/paste the correct json

Comment: that did the trick by checking the actual code i realized the data = list(df.to_dict('index').values()) wasnt implemented as you had suggested. I fixed it as per your instructions and now it works fine . Thank you so much